# Segmentation Fault in multithread program C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I have made the following program as part of my academic project. I have given the entire program since I cannot identify the actual problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<pthread.h>
//Structure for getting dam details
struct dam
{
    float max_height;
    float min_height;
    float sto_capacity;
    float pro_capacity;
    float stn_const;
    float crnt_lvl;
    float delay;
    float crnt_lvl_min;
    float crnt_lvl_max;
    float unit_vol;
    float water_req;
    float work_hr;
    int work_hr_int;
};
//global variables
int n, i, extra_w_hr_int, extra_w_hr_ref, j, k, flag, l, m, swap, pos=11, h, main_flag=1, days_count=0, temp_extra_w_hr_ref;
int jj, k1, flag1, l1, m1, swap1, g=0;
float extra_w_hr, extra_height, diff_level, extra_water;
int rank[24];
int rank1[24];
float rate[24];
float water_pu[24];
float sum_rate1[24];
float avg_rate1[24];
float std_dev_rate1[24];
float temp_rate1[24];
float sum_rate[24];
float avg_rate[24];
float std_dev_rate[24];
float temp_rate[24];
struct dam dam_obj[10];
pthread_t inner_thread[10];
//Thread for increasing water in lower dam after delay
void *inner_function(void *no)
{

    int *num = no;
    if(*num != (n-1))
    {

        sleep(dam_obj[*num-1].delay);

    }
    else if(*num == (n-1))
    {

        sleep(dam_obj[*num].delay);

    }
    dam_obj[*num+1].unit_vol = dam_obj[*num+1].sto_capacity/(dam_obj[*num+1].max_height - dam_obj[*num+1].min_height);
    extra_height = extra_water/dam_obj[*num+1].unit_vol;
    dam_obj[*num+1].crnt_lvl+=extra_height;
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
//Thread for forcasting 7 day details
void *days_function()
{

    while(days_count<7)
    {

        h=n-2;

        while(h>=(pos-1))
        {

            printf("Day-%d\tWorking Hours of dam %d:\t18hrs to 22hrs\n", days_count+1, h);
            dam_obj[h].water_req = (dam_obj[h].pro_capacity*dam_obj[h].work_hr)/(1000*dam_obj[h].stn_const);
            if((h-1)>-1)
            {

                dam_obj[h-1].work_hr = dam_obj[h].water_req*1000*dam_obj[h].stn_const/dam_obj[h-1].pro_capacity;
                dam_obj[h-1].work_hr_int = dam_obj[h-1].work_hr*10;
                temp_extra_w_hr_ref = dam_obj[h-1].work_hr_int%10;
                dam_obj[h-1].work_hr_int/=10;
                if(temp_extra_w_hr_ref>2)
                {

                    dam_obj[h-1].work_hr_int++;

                }

                dam_obj[h-1].work_hr_int-=4;

                //calculate the average and standard deviation of the rates
                jj=0;
                k1=1;
                flag1=1;
                while(flag1=1)
                {

                    if(jj==0 && k1==0)
                    {

                        flag1=0;
                        break;

                    }

                    if(jj>=18 && jj<=22 && (jj+dam_obj[h-1].work_hr_int)>=18 && (jj+dam_obj[h-1].work_hr_int)<=22)
                    {

                        rank1[jj]=25;
                        jj++;
                        sum_rate1[jj]=0;
                        avg_rate1[jj]=0;
                        std_dev_rate1[jj]=0;
                        continue;

                    }

                    rank1[jj]=jj;
                    k1=0;
                    sum_rate1[jj] = 0;
                    for(l1=0;l1<dam_obj[h-1].work_hr_int;l1++)
                    {

                        m1 = jj+l1;
                        if(m1>23)
                        {

                            m1-=24;

                        }
                        sum_rate1[jj]+=rate[m1];

                    }

                    avg_rate1[jj]=sum_rate1[jj]/extra_w_hr_int;

                    for(l1=0;l1<dam_obj[h-1].work_hr_int;l1++)
                    {

                        m1 = jj+l1;
                        if(m1>23)
                        {

                            m1-=24;

                        }

                        temp_rate1[m1]=rate[m1];
                        temp_rate1[m1]=pow((temp_rate1[m1]-avg_rate1[m1]),2);
                        std_dev_rate1[jj]+=temp_rate1[m1];

                    }

                    jj++;

                    if(jj>23)
                    {

                        jj-=24;

                    }

                }

                //Sorting the values
                for(jj=0;jj<(n-1);jj++)
                {

                    for(l1=0;l1<n-jj-1;l1++)
                    {

                        if((avg_rate1[l1]>avg_rate1[l1+1]) || ((avg_rate1[l1]==avg_rate1[l1+1]) && (std_dev_rate1[l1]>std_dev_rate1[l1+1])))
                        {

                            swap1=rank1[l1];
                            rank1[l1]=rank[l1+1];
                            rank[l1+1]=swap1;

                        }

                    }

                }

                printf("Day-%d\tWorking Hours of dam %d:\t18hrs to 22hrs\tand\t%dhrs to %dhrs\n", days_count+1, h-1, rank1[0], rank1[0]+dam_obj[h-1].work_hr_int);

            }

            h--;

        }

        while(g<(pos-1))
        {

            printf("Day-%d\tWorking Hours of dam 1:\t18hrs to 22hrs\n", days_count+1);
            dam_obj[g].water_req = dam_obj[g].pro_capacity*dam_obj[g].work_hr/(1000*dam_obj[g].stn_const);
            dam_obj[g+1].work_hr = dam_obj[g].water_req*1000*dam_obj[g+1].stn_const/dam_obj[g+1].pro_capacity;
            dam_obj[g+1].work_hr_int = dam_obj[g+1].work_hr*10;
            temp_extra_w_hr_ref = dam_obj[g+1].work_hr_int%10;
            dam_obj[g+1].work_hr_int/=10;
            if(temp_extra_w_hr_ref>2)
            {

                dam_obj[g+1].work_hr_int++;

            }
            dam_obj[g+1].work_hr_int-=4;

            //calculate the average and standard deviation of the rates
            jj=0;
            k1=1;
            flag1=1;
            while(flag1=1)
            {

                if(jj==0 && k1==0)
                {

                    flag1=0;
                    break;

                }

                if(jj>=18 && jj<=22 && (jj+dam_obj[g+1].work_hr_int)>=18 && (jj+dam_obj[g+1].work_hr_int)<=22)
                {

                    rank1[jj]=25;
                    jj++;
                    sum_rate1[jj]=0;
                    avg_rate1[jj]=0;
                    std_dev_rate1[jj]=0;
                    continue;

                }

                rank1[jj]=jj;
                k1=0;
                sum_rate1[jj] = 0;
                for(l1=0;l1<dam_obj[g+1].work_hr_int;l1++)
                {

                    m1 = jj+l1;
                    if(m1>23)
                    {

                        m1-=24;

                    }
                    sum_rate1[jj]+=rate[m1];

                }

                avg_rate1[jj]=sum_rate1[jj]/extra_w_hr_int;

                for(l1=0;l1<dam_obj[g+1].work_hr_int;l1++)
                {

                    m1 = jj+l1;
                    if(m1>23)
                    {

                        m1-=24;

                    }

                    temp_rate1[m1]=rate[m1];
                    temp_rate1[m1]=pow((temp_rate1[m1]-avg_rate1[m1]),2);
                    std_dev_rate1[jj]+=temp_rate1[m1];

                }

                jj++;

                if(jj>23)
                {

                    jj-=24;

                }

            }

            //Sorting the values
            for(jj=0;jj<(n-1);jj++)
            {

                for(l1=0;l1<n-jj-1;l1++)
                {

                    if((avg_rate1[l1]>avg_rate1[l1+1]) || ((avg_rate1[l1]==avg_rate1[l1+1]) && (std_dev_rate1[l1]>std_dev_rate1[l1+1])))
                    {

                        swap1=rank1[l1];
                        rank1[l1]=rank[l1+1];
                        rank[l1+1]=swap1;

                    }

                }

            }

            printf("Day-%d\tWorking Hours of dam %d:\t18hrs to 22hrs\tand\t%dhrs to %dhrs\n", days_count+1, g+2, rank1[0], rank1[0]+dam_obj[g+1].work_hr_int);
            g++;

        }

        dam_obj[n-1].water_req = dam_obj[g].water_req - dam_obj[g-1].water_req;
        dam_obj[n-1].work_hr = dam_obj[n-1].water_req*1000*dam_obj[n-1].stn_const/dam_obj[n-1].pro_capacity;
        dam_obj[n-1].work_hr_int = dam_obj[n-1].work_hr*10;
        temp_extra_w_hr_ref = dam_obj[n-1].work_hr_int%10;
        dam_obj[n-1].work_hr_int/=10;
        if(temp_extra_w_hr_ref>2)
        {

            dam_obj[n-1].work_hr_int++;

        }
        dam_obj[n-1].work_hr_int-=4;

        //calculate the average and standard deviation of the rates
        jj=0;
        k1=1;
        flag1=1;
        while(flag1=1)
        {

            if(jj==0 && k1==0)
            {

                flag1=0;
                break;

            }

            if(jj>=18 && jj<=22 && (jj+dam_obj[n-1].work_hr_int)>=18 && (jj+dam_obj[n-1].work_hr_int)<=22)
            {

                rank1[jj]=25;
                jj++;
                sum_rate1[jj]=0;
                avg_rate1[jj]=0;
                std_dev_rate1[jj]=0;
                continue;

            }

            rank1[jj]=jj;
            k1=0;
            sum_rate1[jj] = 0;
            for(l1=0;l1<dam_obj[n-1].work_hr_int;l1++)
            {

                m1 = jj+l1;
                if(m1>23)
                {

                    m1-=24;

                }
                sum_rate1[jj]+=rate[m1];

            }

            avg_rate1[jj]=sum_rate1[jj]/extra_w_hr_int;

            for(l1=0;l1<dam_obj[h-1].work_hr_int;l1++)
            {

                m1 = jj+l1;
                if(m1>23)
                {

                    m1-=24;

                }

                temp_rate1[m1]=rate[m1];
                temp_rate1[m1]=pow((temp_rate1[m1]-avg_rate1[m1]),2);
                std_dev_rate1[jj]+=temp_rate1[m1];

            }

            jj++;

            if(jj>23)
            {

                jj-=24;

            }

        }

        //Sorting the values
        for(jj=0;jj<(n-1);jj++)
        {

            for(l1=0;l1<n-jj-1;l1++)
            {

                if((avg_rate1[l1]>avg_rate1[l1+1]) || ((avg_rate1[l1]==avg_rate1[l1+1]) && (std_dev_rate1[l1]>std_dev_rate1[l1+1])))
                {

                    swap1=rank1[l1];
                    rank1[l1]=rank[l1+1];
                    rank[l1+1]=swap1;

                }

            }

        }

        printf("Day-%d\tWorking Hours of dam %d:\t18hrs to 22hrs\tand\t%dhrs to %dhrs\n", days_count+1, n-1, rank1[0], rank1[0]+dam_obj[n-1].work_hr_int);


    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
//Thread function for working of dams
void *dam_function()
{

    diff_level = dam_obj[i].crnt_lvl - dam_obj[i].crnt_lvl_max;
    dam_obj[i].unit_vol = dam_obj[i].sto_capacity/(dam_obj[i].max_height - dam_obj[i].min_height);
    extra_water = diff_level * dam_obj[i].unit_vol;
    water_pu[i] = dam_obj[i].pro_capacity/(dam_obj[i].stn_const * 1000);
    extra_w_hr = extra_water/water_pu[i];
    extra_w_hr_int = extra_w_hr*10;
    extra_w_hr_ref = extra_w_hr_int%10;
    extra_w_hr_int/=10;
    if(extra_w_hr_ref>2)
    {

        extra_w_hr_int++;

    }

    //calculate the average and standard deviation of the rates
    j=0;
    k=1;
    flag=1;
    while(flag=1)
    {

        if(j==0 && k==0)
        {

            flag=0;
            break;

        }

        if(j>=18 && j<=22 && (j+extra_w_hr_int)>=18 && (j+extra_w_hr_int)<=22)
        {

            rank[j]=25;
            j++;
            sum_rate[j]=0;
            avg_rate[j]=0;
            std_dev_rate[j]=0;
            continue;

        }

        rank[j]=j;
        k=0;
        sum_rate[j] = 0;

        for(l=0;l<extra_w_hr_int;l++)
        {

            m = j+l;
            if(m>23)
            {

                m-=24;

            }
            sum_rate[j]+=rate[m];

        }

        avg_rate[j]=sum_rate[j]/extra_w_hr_int;
        std_dev_rate[j]=0;

        for(l=0;l<extra_w_hr_int;l++)
        {

            m = j+l;
            if(m>23)
            {

                m-=24;

            }
            temp_rate[m]=rate[m];
            temp_rate[m]=pow((temp_rate[m]-avg_rate[m]),2);
            std_dev_rate[j]+=temp_rate[m];

        }

        j++;

        if(j>23)
        {

            j-=24;

        }

    }

    //Sorting the values
    for(j=0;j<(n-1);j++)
    {

        for(l=0;l<n-j-1;l++)
        {

            if((avg_rate[l]>avg_rate[l+1]) || ((avg_rate[l]==avg_rate[l+1]) && (std_dev_rate[l]>std_dev_rate[l+1])))
            {

                swap=rank[l];
                rank[l]=rank[l+1];
                rank[l+1]=swap;

            }

        }

    }

    printf("Hours of extra running: %d\nExtra Working Hours for dam-%d: %d Hours - %d Hours\n", extra_w_hr_int, i, rank[0], rank[0]+extra_w_hr_int);

    if(i+1<n)
    {

        pthread_create (&inner_thread[i], NULL, (void *) &inner_function, &i);
        if(i == pos)
        {

            pthread_create (&inner_thread[pos], NULL, (void *) &inner_function, &pos);

        }

    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

int main()
{

    pthread_t thread[10],days_thread;
    FILE *file = fopen ( "values.txt", "r" );
    dam_obj[n-1].work_hr = 4;
    dam_obj[0].work_hr = 24;
    //printf("Enter the number of dams:\t\t");
    fscanf(file, "%d\n",&n);
    //printf("\n\nThe branched dam should be given as the \'n\'th dam in the set\n\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        //printf("Enter the maximum height of dam-%d:\t",i+1);
        fscanf(file, "%f\n",&dam_obj[i].max_height);    
        //printf("Enter the minimum height of dam-%d:\t",i+1);
        fscanf(file, "%f\n",&dam_obj[i].min_height);    
        //printf("Enter the storage capacity of dam-%d:\t",i+1);
        fscanf(file, "%f\n",&dam_obj[i].sto_capacity);  
        //printf("Enter the production capacity of dam-%d:\t",i+1);
        fscanf(file, "%f\n",&dam_obj[i].pro_capacity);  
        //printf("Enter the station constant of dam-%d:\t",i+1);
        fscanf(file, "%f\n",&dam_obj[i].stn_const); 
        //printf("Enter the current level of dam-%d:\t",i+1);
        fscanf(file, "%f\n",&dam_obj[i].crnt_lvl);  
        //printf("Enter the time delay of dam-%d:\t\t",i+1);
        fscanf(file, "%f\n",&dam_obj[i].delay);

    }

    //printf("Enter the rates for the following hours:\n");
    for(i=0;i<24;i++)
    {

        //printf("%d-%d:\t\t\t",i,i+1);
        fscanf(file, "%f\n",&rate[i]);

    }

    if(n>2)
    {

        //printf("Enter the position at which the stage occurs:\t");
        fscanf(file, "%d\n",&pos);

    }

    for(i=0;(i<n && days_count<7);i++)
    {

        dam_obj[i].crnt_lvl_min=dam_obj[i].max_height * 0.6;
        dam_obj[i].crnt_lvl_max=dam_obj[i].max_height * 0.8;

        //If the current level is greater than allowed maximum level
        if(dam_obj[i].crnt_lvl_max < dam_obj[i].crnt_lvl)
        {
            pthread_create (&thread[i], NULL, (void *) &dam_function, NULL);
            if(i==(n-1))
            {

                i = -1;
                days_count++;

            }

        }

        //Normal Working Condition
        else if(((dam_obj[i].crnt_lvl<dam_obj[i].crnt_lvl_max) && (dam_obj[i].crnt_lvl>dam_obj[i].crnt_lvl_min)) && (main_flag == 1))
        {

            main_flag=0;
            pthread_create (&days_thread, NULL, (void *) &days_function, NULL);

        }

    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

The contents of the file is given below:

```
5
1758.69
1735.836
7.787
28
1.263
1758.69
2
847.6
844.86
1.614
36
.79
847.05
4
456.59
444
5.557
55
.41
452.9
3
253
237.74
4.55
116
.46
247.3
0
707.745
678.8
47.4
32
.472
703.8
2
7
5
6
3
8
3
6
4
5
7
9
1
3
2
4
5
7
8
4
6
7
3
5
9
3
```

I compiled the program in linux using `gcc -o project project.c -pthread -lpthread -lm`
But on running it returned just a `Segmentation Fault`. So I compiled the code for debugging using gdb and after that on running, gdb showed the following:

```
Starting program: /home/anver/project
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0xb7e2db70 (LWP 3778)]
[New Thread 0xb762cb70 (LWP 3779)]
[New Thread 0xb6e2bb70 (LWP 3780)]
[New Thread 0xb662ab70 (LWP 3781)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xb762cb70 (LWP 3779)]
0x08049cd1 in dam_function () at project-file.c:504
504             std_dev_rate[j]+=temp_rate[m];
```

After that when I printed the values of j,l and m I figured out that I am getting very high values for j,l and m which was not expected to go beyond 23. Is there anyway I can resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one is going to spend their afternoon looking through 600+ lines of code.  It is your responsibility to provide a minimal, palatable test case.

Comment: You give as a rationale for posting this wall of code that you couldn't figure out where the problem lies, but didn't gdb do that for you? (`std_dev_rate[j]+=temp_rate[m];`)

Comment: I gave the entire code since I cannot figure out where the actual problem is. As you can see there is a lots of variables and threads used in the program and I couldn't figure out any clue. I have included the results of gdb so that it would be easy to check out.

Comment: @antonijn: Yes. gdb showed me where the segmentation fault came and I figured out that the values of j,l and m are incrementing more than desired. I couldn't figure out how that was happening.

Comment: That dam function is segmentation faulting again.

Comment: if you do need to post this much code I would suggest using something like gist: https://gist.github.com/.  Sometimes that is helpful for people who are interested in reproducing the problem you are asking about. But in your question itself you should narrow down the code you show to at least where you think the problem might be or what you have a question about.

Comment: Was the "academic project" to "write multithreaded code that accesses global variables in a totally insecure manner by avoiding all locking primitives and things like interlocked operations"? If so, well done. There are so many race conditions here, it's not even funny. **SERIOUSLY**. It's just not.

Comment: Just turning on warnings on your compiler (gcc -Wall -Werror) for a start will help you find a couple of issues. This one for example: while(flag1=1)

Comment: The cure for segmentation faults is [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).  In this case you also want to apply [helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html) to find and squelch inter-thread race conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pthreads standard specifies that accessing a variable on one thread while it is, or might be, modified in another is undefined behavior. Your function, `days_function` does this with the variables `days_count`, among many other variables in many other places.

Bluntly, it looks like you have no idea how to properly use threads.